# Framework7 autocomplete working only locally

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I have this autocomplete element from Framework7:

```
var autocompleteDropdownSimple = myApp.autocomplete({
    input: '#autocomplete-dropdown',
    openIn: 'dropdown',
    source: function (autocomplete, query, render) {
        var results = [];
        names = ["name1","framework","server","local","bank"]
        if (query.length === 0) {
            render(results);
            return;
        }
        // Find matched items
        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (names[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
                results.push(names[i]);   
            }
        }
        // Render items by passing array with result items
        render(results);
    },
    onClose: function () {
    },
    onError: function() {
    }
});
```

My problem is that autocomplete works fine only if my html file is loaded locally (file://...). If this run on a webserver (such as PhoneGap or python simplehttpserver) i have no autocomplete and no suggestion while typing. 
How is that possible?

All other js functions are working fine, like alert() on page init, so js files are correctly loaded.

Comment: Check the error in console.. One thing more make it sure that javascript files are uploaded there on server  i.e. PhoneGap etc.

Comment: @Faraz console shows no error and js files are correctly loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved adding that code in onInit function of relative page.